# How can I immediately get the size of QWidget on resizing?

Tags: qt, resize, qwidget

I am trying to get the real-time size when a QWidget resized. The problem which I am facing now is when I click and hold mouse on window border and start to resize, then the size which I receive in the `resizeEvent()` function, is all the same (e.g: 400) not changing till I leave the mouse button, and click again to resize, after that last resized size can be received.

Now; how to get the real size during the dragging the mouse? Something in Java `componentResized(ComponentEvent e)` which is the same firing the event and when you call `getWidth()`, then it will return the new width.

Comment: [QResizeEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qresizeevent.html)

Comment: @MarekR  Thank you, man!!